# Is there a way to add a custom file filter to Visual Studio's open file dialog through a VSIX extension?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, mef, vsix, vspackage

I'm implementing a set of MEF extensions through a VSIX extension project. This is for a small internal DSL.

I can get syntax highlighting working just fine.

What I would like to do is to be able to have an associated file filter entry in the Open File dialog in Visual Studio.

Is there a way to do this through a VSIX extension? If not, what is the sanctioned way to add filters to that list?

I didn't see anything in the VSPackage system that could do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you developed package with the custom Language Service only, and you wish to be able create yourown projects of your custom Project Type - you need to develop a Project System (see [IronPython Project System Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb165776%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166376%28VS.80%29.aspx)).

But if you just want to add your custom extension to one of the existing project groups in Open File dialog - you just need to create custom item template. Somthing like this:

```
<VSTemplate Version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Item">
  <TemplateData>
    <DefaultName>Class.my</DefaultName>
    <Name>MY File Class</Name>
    <Description>An empty class definition</Description>
    <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
    <ProjectType>[PUT HERE THE PROJECT TYPE YOU WANT TO PLACE YOUR TEMPLATE UNDER]</ProjectType>
    <SortOrder>10</SortOrder>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <References />
    <ProjectItem SubType="Code" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.my" ReplaceParameters="true">Class.my</ProjectItem>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

The [easiest way](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/04/creating-and-sharing-project-item-templates.aspx) to craete a new template is to extract existing, unpack from ZIP, adjust all you need and install it back into IDE. But you could also create it from scratch and install during your setup within the VS. I guess you have enough pointers to digg deeper ;)

Comment: I need some time to look into this. I'll accept your answer when I've verified that it was what I'm looking for. Thanks.